# Releasing an Array Object

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablearray

According to Instruments analysis, I have a memory leak here - and - I'm unsure as to how to properly release the scoresArray object that I have created.

This code does work properly, apart from the leakage. I release the highScoresArray object later in the code - but attempts to release the scoresArray kill the app. I thought that when I released highScoresArray, that I would release scoresArray, since they both point to the same location in memory. If anyone can point out where my thinking is flawed, that would be great.

```
- (void) readScoresFile {
    // Read the Scores File, if it exists
    NSString *filePath = [self scoresFilePath];
    // Only load the file if it exists at the path
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: filePath]) {
        scoresFileExistsFlag = YES;
        NSLog(@"SCORES FILE EXISTS - THEREFORE LOAD IT");
        NSMutableArray *scoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
        highScoresArray = scoresArray;
    } else {
        scoresFileExistsFlag = NO;
        NSMutableArray *scoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        highScoresArray = scoresArray;

        // No Scores File exists - we need to create and save an empty one.
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter <= 5) {
            // Set up a date object and format same for inclusion in the Scores file
            NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy.MM.dd"]; 
            NSString *theDateNow = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
            // Add the score data (Score and User and date) to the runScoreDataDictionary
            runScoreDataDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"score", 
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"landings",
                currentUser, @"user", 
                theDateNow, @"date", nil];
            //NSLog(@"Dictionary contains: %@", runScoreDataDictionary);
            // Add the dictionary to the highScoreArray
            [highScoresArray addObject:runScoreDataDictionary];
            //NSLog(@"OBJECTS in ARRAY: %i", [highScoresArray count]);

            [self writeScoresFile]; // Write the empty scores file to disk

            [now release];
            [dateFormat release]; 

            ++counter;

            //[scoresArray release]; // TESTING TO SEE IF THIS KILLS - YES KILLS
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `highScoresArray` is an instance variable (since it's not declared anywhere in the method you listed). This means that upon creation of `scoresArray` (which is the same object as `highScoresArray`) it has a retain count of 1. You don't `retain` it, so `release`ing it will decrement its retain count to 0 and it will be cleaned up -- not a good thing for an instance variable.

I'm also not sure why you do this:

```
NSMutableArray *scoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
highScoresArray = scoresArray;
```

You don't seem to need to use `scoresArray` anywhere else, so you could just do this:

```
[highScoresArray release];    // Release the old object
highScoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Yes - highScoresArray is a instance variable - I've eliminated the extraneous scoresArray - thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

> I release the highScoresArray object later in the code - but attempts to release the scoresArray kill the app. I thought that when I released highScoresArray, that I would release scoresArray, since they both point to the same location in memory

**As long as you haven't changed** the `highScoresArray` pointer to point to another object, releasing it will be the same as releasing `scoresArray`.

```
NSMutableArray* highScoresArray;
NSMutableArray* scoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
highScoresArray = scoresArray;
[highScoresArray release]; // same as `[scoresArray release];`
```

But if you change either of them afterwards to point to another object, releasing them won't be equivalent:

```
NSMutableArray* highScoresArray;
NSMutableArray* scoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
highScoresArray = scoresArray;
// ... Now make `highScoresArray` point to another object ...
highScoresArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// Now you should release both as they point to different objects.
[highScoresArray release];
[scoresArray release];
```

Of course, simply calling `addObject` doesn't alter the *pointer*. It changes the object being *pointed to*. Only reassigning the pointer to another object matters here.